Getting the dependencies of a compiled .jar
I have a java jar and I've decompiled it. Inside the pom.xml there are a lot of dependecies used in local, that is, they use the system and a scopePath that is the project's.
I need to take the jars of those dependencies. Is there a way to do that?
Let me clarify the question. I have a jar that I "dejarrated" and inside the "Manifest" I have the pom.xml of the jar. Unfortunately some dependencies used are local jars (not online downloaded by maven) of the author that he imported into maven by inserting the parameter "system therefore contained in the initial source code. I would need one of these libraries in its entirety.

Your question sounds like nonsense: "I have a jar that I decompiled and I also have the build file" makes no sense. If you have the source, why decompile? If you don't have the source, where did pom.xml come from? What does 'system and a scopePath' mean? These aren't things you end up with when you decompile class files.

I am not sure if I understand the problem. You can write an app that reads the POM and searches your local repository for the jars. If they are not found locally, have your app download the jars from the Maven repository.

One way to make sense of your question is to assume that you have a jar containing source code and that you have, not decompiled it but 'unjarred' it. Is that the case?

Yes, let me clarify the question. I have a jar that I "dejarrated" and inside the "Manifest" I have the pom.xml of the jar. Unfortunately some dependencies used are local jars (not online downloaded by maven) of the author that he imported into maven by inserting the parameter "system therefore contained in the initial source code. I would need one of these libraries in its entirety.

If you clarify a question in length in the comments you might want to consider editing the question to clarify your problem

Done, edited my question, thanks.

You need the word 'unzipped' probably ( a jar is just a zip archive).  If the extra jar dependencies are not named as in, and present in,  public repositories, then you need to get them from the developer

How is the JAR expected to be run? If these dependencies are required, you need to have them for running the application so you probably either got them with the JAR (possibly without knowing) or the dependencies may be shaded in which case you don't really need to declare/add them.

some dependencies used are local jars means that these jars may be private jars. Your question can be transformed into another question: Is it possible to obtain the private jars in someone's computer?

@rzwitserloot A lot of JAR files built with Maven contain pom.xml in subdirectory of META-INF/maven inside the JAR file. therefore it is not uncommon to have a Jar file without sources but the pom.xml.
